# Can't run BackstopJS interactive reporting

Tags: angular, testing, regression-testing, backstop.js

I'm able to generate backstop reports and see them as static pages, but when I try to load the interactive report provided by `backstop remote` I get the following message in the browser:

```
Cannot GET /
```

I have tried new and old LTS versions of `node` and downgrading from `backstopjs@6` to `backstopjs@5` but nothing changed.

What's going on?